# Como fazer um array do value com select multiple

Tags: jquery, html

o Cenário é o seguinte, eu tenho um select multiple com as opções do tipo de atividade de cada pessoa cadastrada no sistema, porém a mesma pessoa pode ser um cliente e um funcionário, porém ao serializar o form com jquery estou recebendo várias variaveis do meu select.

```
let form = $('#form-pessoas-cadastrar').serializeArray();
console.log(form);
```

[image: resultado do console.log(form)]

```
$.post('/api/pessoas/store',form); // Só salva o ultimo valor "atividades[]=5"
```

Meu problema é nessa parte, eu não consigo serializar o select para salvar os valores na mesma coluna do banco de dados `pessoas.atividades('1,3,5')` depois também tenho que fazer o inverso, trazer os valores do banco pro select.

Comment: Como foram definidas as atividades no banco de dados ? Qual a estrutura da tabela(s) relacionada(s) ?

Comment: @Isac mysql, varchar(10).

Comment: E como iria guardar os vários valores num `varchar(10)`? Já para não falar que essa modelação não está correta pois irá criar dificuldades mais tarde em relacionar atividades com funcionarios/clientes

Comment: o que você sugere?

Comment: Se cada cliente e/ou funcionario pode atender várias atividades então a modelação correta seria criar uma tabela aparte que associe cliente/funcionario com atividade. Isto no entanto não está diretamente relacionado com o problema que indica na pergunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema ajustando o html, e tratando com jquery da seguinte maneira.

```
// Alterei o source html/pug com os valores legíveis de cada atividade.
label.col-md-1.control-label Atividades
div.col-md-2
select.form-control(multiple='', style="width: 100%", name='atividades_temp')
  optgroup(label='Atividades')
    option(value='Cliente') Cliente
    option(value='Proprietário') Proprietário
    option(value='Colaborador') Colaborador
    option(value='Transportador') Transportador
    option(value='Armazenador') Armazenador

// seletor jquery do select atividades_temp
let $atv = $("select[name='atividades_temp']");

// Usei um input para alocar as informações vindas do select atividades_temp
$('input.select2-search__field').attr({name: 'atividades', type: 'hidden'});

// no evento OnClick do botão submit eu pego o array do multiple select 
// e adiciono no input hidden, para serializar o form.
$("input[name='atividades']").val($atv.val().toString());            
console.log($atv.val().toString()); // "Cliente,Proprietário,Colaborador,Transportador"
let form = $('#form-pessoas-cadastrar').serializeArray();
$.post(urlApi, form);
```

**Resumo:** 
Um `select multiple` cria um array com as opções selecionadas, porém a função `toString()` do js transforma o objeto array para um objeto string, dessa forma eu posso fatiar e tratar como necessário.